# Selectively disable REPORTTIME for an application

Tags: zsh

The ZSH parameter `REPORTTIME` tells the user how long a command took, if it runs for longer than a certain threshold.

Is there a way to disable it for a certain application? My use case is a terminal-based text editor. Editing sessions can take any amount of time, but since the bottleneck is my coding speed, I'm not particularly interested in knowing their length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wrapper function should suppress the timing summary for a single command:

```sh
function noreporttime {
  local REPORTTIME=-1
  "$@"
}
# enable tab completion for wrapped commands
compdef _precommand noreporttime
```

You could use this in an alias to disable it for a certain application.

Comment: Does `local REPORTTIME=-1` work without having to worry about traps?

Comment: Huh, it does work. I could have sworn I tried that, but I guess not. Thanks!